# Why the mouseX and mouseY values are all the time 0 when moving the mouse around over the texture2d?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Texture2DRaycastHit : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Texture2D texture2DSpriteWithClouds;
    private Vector2 mousePos = new Vector2();
    private RectTransform rect;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        var rawImage = GetComponent<RawImage>();
        rect = rawImage.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        texture2DSpriteWithClouds = rawImage.texture as Texture2D;
        Color[] texture2dWithCloudsPixels = texture2DSpriteWithClouds.GetPixels();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        RectTransformUtility.ScreenPointToLocalPointInRectangle(rect,
            Input.mousePosition, Camera.main, out mousePos);

        print("Mouse Pos X " + mousePos.x + " Mouse Pos Y " + mousePos.y);
    }
}
```

the script is attached to object with rawimage and the rawimage source image is a texture2d.

in the texture field it's s1.

[image: rawimage]

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to change in the Canvas (the rawimage is under a canvas) the Render Mode to Screen Space - Camera and then to assign the camera to the Render Camera field.